# Radial Plane Topology

Tags: general-topology

A subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ is radially open if it contains an open line segment in each direction about each of its points.

If $A$ is a subset of the plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $A$ intersects any line in at most 2 points, prove that $\mathbb{R^2}/A$ is radially open.

Ok, so I have to prove that in $\mathbb{R^2}/A$ there is an open line segment in each direction about each of its points.

If $x$ is in $\mathbb{R^2}/A$ then an infinite amount of lines pass through $x$. So I can take segments of those lines, such that $x$ is in each one of those segments. 
Then $\mathbb{R^2}/A$ is radially open.

I don´t think I´m getting the idea, because I´m not using the property of $A$, that it intersects in at most 2 points of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Can you help generate and formalize this proof please?

Answer (score 3):

Prove this by contradiction. Suppose that we have an $x\in\mathbb R^2\setminus A$ and a direction vector $e$ such that there is no line segment $[x,\epsilon e]$ completely contained in $\mathbb R^2\setminus A$ however small we pick $\epsilon>0.$ That means that there exists a sequence $\epsilon_n$ converging to 0 such that the points $x+\epsilon_n e$ belong to $A,$ contradicting the fact that $A$ contains at most two points of the line going through $x$ which is parallel to $e.$